# How can i call Javascript function from serverside java code and pass data to it?

Tags: javascript, java, server

I have Dynamic Web Application deployed on Glassfish server. Inside my application I have a java function that is invoked every time certain JMS Message is received. Depending on JMS Message, I want to update the state of web application that is loaded inside web browser - I need to call certain Javascript function as soon as the JMS Message is received.

How can i accomplish that? Is there any java and/or Javscript library that can do this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

P.S. After Some research i have found a very useful library that does exactly what i wanted: [DWR - Direct Web Remoting](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)

Comment: you want to "push" data to browser? [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) perhaps? or [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) look more up your alley

Answer (score 1):

Old way: by polling at a certain interval

New way: by using websockets,

http://vertx.io/ provides a good library to achieve this.

You can see sample here http://vertx.io/blog/real-time-bidding-with-websockets-and-vert-x/

Comment: thank you. I will give it a try

Comment: I have found following java library that does exactly what i wanted and is very usefull:   http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html